# Python divisible range

Tags: python, range

So I'm doing simple problems online to get an understanding of Python and came across this one:

> Add all numbers in the range 1..1000 inclusive where the number is odd
>   but is divisible by any number in the range 2..(n // 2) inclusive.

My attempt:

```
total = 0
for num in range(1, 1000, 2):
    if all(num % n == 0 for n in range(2, num // 2)):
        total += num
print(total)
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the way I'm implementing it, getting an output of 9, instead of the expected output of 173874.

Comment: Perhaps you want `any` instead of `all`?

Comment: @mgilson Add it as an answer

Comment: according to your problem statement you should use `range(lower_bound, upper_bound + 1)` if you want `[lower_bound, upper_bound]` mathematically (inclusive lower_bound and upper_bound)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `any`

```
total = 0
for num in range(1, 1000, 2):
    if any(num % n == 0 for n in range(2, num // 2)):
        total += num
print(total)
```

when you used `all` you are only summing up 1,3,5 because `all` Return True only if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). In your case, you want `any` which returns True if any element of the iterable is true.

Comment: oops. did not see mgilson already answer it as I was typing it up. mgilson answered it before me please mark his/her/their answer as the solution.

Comment: [I believe mglison is actual _"Matt Gilson"](https://github.com/mgilson)_ - a man.

Comment: Well to be polite I didn't want to make assumption on Matt's preferred gender pronounce.